# Copy data up to last row and column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy all the data from multiple workbooks to a single workbook and distribute them to different worksheets.

How should I change the code below to automatically select the data up to the last row and column with value and copy them instead of declaring the range?

```
For i = 16 To ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Sheet1 is MasterSheet
    File = ws.Range("C" & i) & ws.Range("I" & i) 'File Location and Excel Name
    Copy = ws.Range("U" & i) & ":" & ws.Range("V" & i) 'Range to be copied
    Workbooks.Open File, 0, 1 'Open File as Read Only
    Range(Copy).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Range("W" & i).Value).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial 12 'Paste as Values only
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False 'Close WorkBook without saving
    Selection.Value = Selection.FormulaR1C1 'Force F2 and Enter selected range

    Range("A1").Select

Next i
```

Comment: try `.UsedRange.Copy`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works fine, Paolo. I did quite a bit of research on the topic some time ago and I found out these ways are the fastest and simplest ones. I don't think Excel is very good with these things, so I have always tried to stick to the basics.

Just two comments:

- I would not use `.UsedRange.Copy`, since it will return the range of cells that have **ever** been used.
- I would also try to avoid using`.select` as much as possible. You can find examples on how to avoid it in 
  [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba][1])